# Strange process while turning off my computer

Tags: windows, windows-10

So I was on my way to turn off my computer when unexpectedly, in the screen where you see the programs that block Windows to turn off, i saw one process with a strange name like {4593-9493-8949-9390} (not the exact same name but similar) and before i could click on the cancel button the process close.

My question here is if I should be wondering about that strange process or its just some random Windows 10 routine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This very well could be a malware of sort being executed in the background. I would recommend scanning your computer with your preferred anti-virus program and then installing [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) which should help you detect and analyze suspicious processes running on your computer:

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the fast answer.

Using process monitor I ended up seeing that the number I mentioned before was like... some kind of &amp;amp;quot;Windows defender virus definition&amp;amp;quot;? I ran the scan in my computer which led me to delete one corrupted file and the number did not appear again in the screen while the turn off and process monitor check.